# Configuration for JMS Input node in IIB 9.0.0.2 for Tibco_EMS Subscription

Tags: jms, tibco-ems, ibm-integration-bus

I have to configure my JMS input node in IIB for JMS Provider Tibco_EMS. TIBCO EMS has provided jar files. I configured the jar files in CLASSPATH and set the jarsurl using mqsichangeproperties and deployed the same. But i am getting error "**There is a configuration problem with the JNDI Administered objects where:  Initial Context Factory  = com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory**'"
 The exception text is : 'Name not found: '' The node cannot obtain a JNDI Administered Object, because some of the values specified are incorrect.   Check the JNDI Administered configuration for the JMS provider used by the node.

But  using some java code with the same configuration is able to connect to Tibco.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you create the administered objects?  Did you use the Tibco tool or the IBM tool?